# Galeria Fotografias

Tags: html, galeria

Estou com uma dificuldade em fazer umas alterações na galeria de fotografias.
http://jsfiddle.net/Qpm5g/

Gostava de colocar tempo para as imagens irem passando.
Gostava de conseguir alterar os botões para um canto em cima das fotografias.

```
   #slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
     position: absolute;
     left: 250 px;
     top:150px;
     bottom: 15px;
     z-index: 100;
     visibility: hidden;
     }
```

Alterei o "Top" e não move a localização dos botões. 
Se alguém me conseguir dizer o que estou a fazer de errado agradecia.

Comment: É isto que queres http://jsfiddle.net/Qpm5g/1/?

Comment: Qual o campo que alterou? E consigo colocar tempo para as imagens irem-se alterando?

Comment: Quero colocar os botões mesmo em cima da fotografia.

Comment: Vê a minha resposta. e tens aqui o link: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpm5g/2/

Comment: Para as imagens se irem alterando já tens de usar JQuery, vê aqui o JavaScript que adicionei: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpm5g/7/. vou alterar a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar o posicionamento dos botões tem de mexer na `label`, alterei isto:

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    ...
    /*bottom: -45px;*/
    top: 0px;
    ...
}
```

Quanto ao mudar de imagem de x em x tempo podes usar o `jQuery` como por [exemplo](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/):

```
$(function(){
    $('#slideshow-inner img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#slideshow-inner :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('#slideshow-inner');}, 
      1000); //tempo de transição
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpm5g/7/)